# Messages freezes my MacBook Air and requires me to re-login

Tags: macos, messages, performance, ventura

Longtime follower of this remarkable community, first time asking a question because so many questions are already answered.

Long story short, this has been happening only lately, like the past two weeks.

Whenever I am running messages on my MacBook Air after about, I don't know, let's say five minutes, it causes the entire system to freeze to the point where I can't even move my cursor.

Then it logged me off and requires me to log back in again. It seems to only happen with this one program. It might've happened with another program, not sure, but I think it's only this program. Any ideas why? Also, I'm not certain, but I think if I use the dictation feature it happens quicker, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I edited your post to remove the second question as it’s one topic per ask.  But to save you time; yes you can downgrade all the way back to what your Mac originally shipped with. If you want to do that, it might solve your freezing issue to do a clean reinstall.  Just make sure you have a good backup